# Powerapps canvas app set container height not working

Tags: powerapps-canvas, power-platform

I am working on a power apps canvas app where I am using containers to manage the layout, but there is an issue setting the containers height, the height is not being reflected, every time I have to delete and undo for the element to apply to height, and after then I do save and return to the app to find that the container is back to its original height of 200.

[image]

[image]

First Image is when I insert the container.
Second Image is after I delete and undo.

Any clue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if there are settings that override the value you set in the Height property:

1. If the Flexible Height property is enabled, the container will stretch to fill all available space vertically.
2. If the container has a parent container, it can be set up so that it's contents fill the available space.

Comment: Great answer, it was the "Flexible Height" property, I turned it off and heights changed to what I set it.